# Multiple jinja2 extensions?

Tags: python, jinja2, webapp2

I want to add multiple jinja2 etensions but I don't know the syntax. This is my current config:

```
config = {  'webapp2_extras.sessions': {
    'cookie_name': '_simpleauth_sess',
    'secret_key': SESSION_KEY
  },
  'webapp2_extras.auth': {
    'user_attributes': []
  },'webapp2_extras.jinja2': {'template_path': 'templates',
          'filters': {'timesince': filters.timesince,
          'datetimeformat': filters.datetimeformat,
    'slugify_montao' : filters.slugify_montao,
'format_datetime_human' : filters.format_datetime_human,
'default_if_none' : filters.default_if_none,
'datetimeformat_viewad': filters.datetimeformat_viewad,
'datetimeformat_jinja': filters.datetimeformat_jinja,
},
          'environment_args': {'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.i18n']}},
          'webapp2_extras.sessions': {'secret_key': 'my-245-key'}}
```

I want to add the entension `env = Environment(extensions=['jinja2htmlcompress.SelectiveHTMLCompress'])` but I don't know how to have more than one. Can you show me?

Thank you

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/

### Update

Seeing the answer below, I've edited my config object to this:

> config = {  'webapp2_extras.sessions': {
>       'cookie_name': '_simpleauth_sess',
>       'secret_key': SESSION_KEY },   'webapp2_extras.auth': {
>       'user_attributes': []   },'webapp2_extras.jinja2': {'template_path': 'templates',
>             'filters': {'timesince': filters.timesince,
>             'datetimeformat': filters.datetimeformat,   'slugify_montao' : filters.slugify_montao, 'format_datetime_human' :
>   filters.format_datetime_human, 'default_if_none' :
>   filters.default_if_none, 'datetimeformat_viewad':
>   filters.datetimeformat_viewad, 'datetimeformat_jinja':
>   filters.datetimeformat_jinja, },
>             'environment_args': {'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.i18n', 'jinja2htmlcompress.SelectiveHTMLCompress']}},
>             }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple extensions can be specified as additional elements of the original list.

```
...
'environment_args': {'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.i18n', 
                                    'jinja2htmlcompress.SelectiveHTMLCompress']}
...
```

I have to say, though, your `config` dictionary appears to be irregularly formatted.
One problem in particular is that you appear to have two `'webapp2_extras.sessions'` keys which will not work.